# How do I delete specific text in multiple cells at once?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office-for-mac

I have a massive list of email addresses; but just to make things simple i am dealing with 3 - 10 email addresses that are typed up in 1 cell and i cant seem to **MASS** delete specific ones. Is there any way I can delete a specific email address from the cell, **GIVEN** that I have a list of specific email addresses that i want to delete. Is it a matter of finding duplicates and deleting or is there more to this?

To elaborate::

**in cell A2 I have** abc@abc.com aaa@abc.com bbb@abc.com ccc@abc.com

**in cell A3 I have** xyz@xyz.com xxx@xyz.com yyy@xyz.com zzz@xyz.com

**In cell H1 to H5** I have abc@abc.com xxx@xyz.com bbb@abc.com ccc@abc.com yyy@xyz.com (each email address is in individual cells)

Is there any way that I can delete a specific email address from A2 and A3 so that I am only left with aaa@abc.com, xyz@xyz.com and zzz@xyz.com?

**Additional Info: I am using Excel for Mac 2011**

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do to your follow up question - [Can I run this Macro faster?](https://superuser.com/q/951455/116196) - I'm submitting my answer here and voting to close that question as a duplicate.

---

If I understand you, you want to take all the values in column H and delete them from column E? I'd do that with some arrays to speed it up -

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoTheThing()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastrow As Integer
'Find last row in column H to size our array
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row

'Declare the array and then resize it to fit column H
Dim varkeep() As Variant
ReDim varkeep(lastrow - 1)

'Load column H into the array
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To lastrow - 1
    varkeep(i) = Range("H" & i + 1)
Next

Dim member As Variant
'find last row in column E
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row

'loop each cell in column E starting in row 2 ending in lastrow
For i = 2 To lastrow
    'Make a new array
    Dim myArray As Variant
    'Load the cell into the array
    myArray = Split(Cells(i, 5), " ")
    Dim k As Integer
    'for each member of this array
    For k = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        member = myArray(k)
        'call the contains function to check if the member exists in column H
        If Contains(varkeep, member) Then
            'if it does, set it to nothing
            myArray(k) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next
    'let's reprint the array to the cell before moving on to the next cell in column E
    Cells(i, 5) = Trim(Join(myArray, " "))
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function Contains(arr As Variant, m As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim tf As Boolean
    'Start as false
    tf = False
    Dim j As Integer
        'Search for the member in the keeparray
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(j) = m Then
                'if it's found, TRUE
                tf = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        'Return the function as true or false for the if statement
        Contains = tf
End Function
```

This creates an array out of column H. Then it goes through each cell in column E, parses it to an array, searches each member of that array against the keep array and if found, deletes that member of the array. After going through the cell, it reprints the array with the found ones missing.

---

Arrays are generally faster than going item by item, but additionally, we're creating our own function rather than using the *slow* `Find and Replace` method. The only issue being that there may be extra spaces within the data. If so, we can run a quick find and replace for that. I found it easier to set the members of the array to nothing rather than to re-size the array and move the elements.

---

Just for completeness' sake, here's a routine that removes extra spaces from column E

```
Sub ConsecSpace()
Dim c As Range
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Dim strValue As String
For Each c In Range("E2:E" & lastrow)
    strValue = c.Value
    Do While InStr(1, strValue, "  ")
        strValue = Replace(strValue, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    c = strValue
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This code ran faster and got done in no time. I believe you helped me out with a previous question before, really cannot thank you, and the others for helping me through this, enough.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand, the best thing you can do here is use the *Find and Replace*

Find the email you want, and replace it with an empty value.

This may have negative effects on your H value though but if you find and replace manually (one at a time) it should be easy and quick enough.

A VBa solution - Take a back up first.

As per your example, I've assumed your look up starts at H1 and ends at some point.

I've also assumed the other data starts on A2 and ends some row in A

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoTheThing()
 Dim keepValueCol As String
 keepValueCol = "H"               'You may need to update this

 Dim row As Integer
 row = 2                          'what row do the values start in column A

 Dim keepValueRow As Integer
 keepValueRow = 1

 Do While (Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

    Do While (Range(keepValueCol & keepValueRow).Value <> "")

    Range("A" & row).Value = Replace(Range("A" & row).Value, Range(keepValueCol & keepValueRow).Value, "")
    Range("A" & row).Value = Trim(Replace(Range("A" & row).Value, "  ", " "))

    keepValueRow = keepValueRow + 1
    Loop


 keepValueRow = 1
 row = row + 1
 Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If i go down your suggested route of find and replace one by one, it will take me ages to do so. I am working with over 2000 specific email addresses that need to be deleted within cells. I am looking for a faster way to do this. But i appreciate your help!

Comment: I could help if you had the real version of Excel, because it can be done in VBa quite easily! Sorry @Jase

Comment: Office for Mac does have a Developer Option which includes Macros and Visual Basic Editor. Is there a way for you to help given these 2 functions?

Comment: I can also get my hands on a PC if my issue has an easy fix. @Dave

Comment: @Jase, updated, see if that helps

Comment: Sorry, there was a fault. updated

Comment: NO NO IT WORKED!!!! OH WOW THANK YOU SO MUCH @DAVE! I REALLY APPRECIATE IT! Ive been pulling the little hair i have left! You are a life saver! THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Pleasure, glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your email list you want to delete, just select the range and replace it by an empty string, like this:

```
Sub Replace_Email_List()

Dim rList as Range, rReplace as Range
Dim sEMail as String

'' Following your Example
Set rList = Range("H1",Range("H1").End(xlDown)) '' or just Range("H1:H5")
Set rReplace = Range("A1",Range("A1").End(xlDown)) '' or just Range("A1:A2")

For i = 1 to rList.Row
    sEMail = rList(i,1)

    rReplace.Replace What:=sEmail, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
Next i

End Sub
```

Hope my answer help you