# Can I run this Macro faster?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am using this macro for over 1000 entries. The code itself works the way I want it to.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoTheThing()
 Dim keepValueCol As String
 keepValueCol = "H"

 Dim row As Integer
 row = 2

 Dim keepValueRow As Integer
 keepValueRow = 1

 Do While (Range("E" & row).Value <> "")

    Do While (Range(keepValueCol & keepValueRow).Value <> "")

    Range("E" & row).Value = Replace(Range("E" & row).Value, Range(keepValueCol & keepValueRow).Value, "")
    Range("E" & row).Value = Trim(Replace(Range("E" & row).Value, "  ", " "))

    keepValueRow = keepValueRow + 1
    Loop


 keepValueRow = 1
 row = row + 1
 Loop

End Sub
```

The problem I am having is that the Macro takes forever to run; to give you an idea, this macro is being running for 4 hours on +1000 entries and I don't know when its going to end.

Is there a way this code can be optimized to run quicker and not compromise the integrity of the code itself?

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a nested loop so instead of looking at the 1000 rows you are doing it 1000^2 or a total of 1 million loops across the rows.

Comment: @cybernard will it change the effect of the code if I remove the loop? and If you say no, could you please tell me how to remove the loop so that the code still does what its supposed to and nothing goes wrong please?

Comment: Trim(Replace(Range("E" & row).Value, "  ", " "))  If I read this correctly search for 2 space and replace it with 1 and then trim the space off, resulting in NULL.  This simplifies to **Replace(Range("E" & row).Value, "  ", "")**  or Replace 2 space with NULL which is 2 quote marks with nothing between them.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean. But in the code, there is loop written twice towards the end... Should i delete that or no?

Comment: Do you intend for your macro to search E1 for all value in H (say h1:h1000) and replace it with NULL ("") and then move to E2 and research the whole H column?  OR Do you just want to search E1 for H1 and E2 for H2?

Comment: Are you putting the macro on each line you want it to run on?  Where are the 1000 times on the spreadsheet?  You may not need a loop increasing the speed dramatically.

Comment: How many rows have values in column H?

Comment: Is column H a full match or partial match.  If E1 contains "SOMESTUFF"  would H contain "STUFF" leaving you will "SOME" left in the cell or would H contain "SOMESTUFF" leaving the cell empty. typically?

Comment: @cybernard

This was my Original post, the gentleman was kind enough to write that code, but as my list got larger, the code failed to work even after 8 hours of running (which it has been now). 

http://superuser.com/questions/937360/how-do-i-delete-specific-text-in-multiple-cells-at-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you want to take all the values in column H and delete them from column E? I'd do that with some arrays to speed it up -

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoTheThing()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastrow As Integer
'Find last row in column H to size our array
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row

'Declare the array and then resize it to fit column H
Dim varkeep() As Variant
ReDim varkeep(lastrow - 1)

'Load column H into the array
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To lastrow - 1
    varkeep(i) = Range("H" & i + 1)
Next

Dim member As Variant
'find last row in column E
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row

'loop each cell in column E starting in row 2 ending in lastrow
For i = 2 To lastrow
    'Make a new array
    Dim myArray As Variant
    'Load the cell into the array
    myArray = Split(Cells(i, 5), " ")
    Dim k As Integer
    'for each member of this array
    For k = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        member = myArray(k)
        'call the contains function to check if the member exists in column H
        If Contains(varkeep, member) Then
            'if it does, set it to nothing
            myArray(k) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next
    'let's reprint the array to the cell before moving on to the next cell in column E
    Cells(i, 5) = Trim(Join(myArray, " "))
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function Contains(arr As Variant, m As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim tf As Boolean
    'Start as false
    tf = False
    Dim j As Integer
        'Search for the member in the keeparray
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(j) = m Then
                'if it's found, TRUE
                tf = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        'Return the function as true or false for the if statement
        Contains = tf
End Function
```

This creates an array out of column H. Then it goes through each cell in column E, parses it to an array, searches each member of that array against the keep array and if found, deletes that member of the array. After going through the cell, it reprints the array with the found ones missing.

---

Arrays are generally faster than going item by item, but additionally, we're creating our own function rather than using the *slow* `Find and Replace` method. The only issue being that there may be extra spaces within the data. If so, we can run a quick find and replace for that. I found it easier to set the members of the array to nothing rather than to re-size the array and move the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the calculations to manual?
(In Excel 2013) `Formulas - Calculation Options - Manual`

It looks your intent is to remove all occurrences of the values in column "H" in the values in column "E".

Have you considered exporting the content and using a tool other than excel to perform the changes you desire?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing, but the only difference is that multiple values I want to remove from Column E are in cells. The H column is like a reference point of what i want to remove from cells in E.

I am using 2011 office for MAC. - what tool can easily sort all this data out? I haven't considered it, but it sounds like a simpler option? is it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is updating the values in column E by removing any values it finds in column H. However, it is doing it very inefficiently by looking at only one cell each time. You can do much better by dealing with the entire range in column E at once. Also, even when you're looking at a single cell, it's easier to use a Range object to access it rather than combining a string for the column and a number for the row.

This code should do the same thing as yours, but it processes all the values in column E at once using the Replace method of the Range object (which is the same functionality as when you do a Replace All in the UI). This should be much faster.

In the first `Replace` call below, the `True` for the final argument indicates a case-sensitive match. If you want a case-insensitive match, change this to `False`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoTheThing()

  Dim UpdateRange As Range, ReplaceCell As Range, dummy As Boolean

  Set UpdateRange = Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown))
  Set ReplaceCell = Range("H1")

  Do While (ReplaceCell.Value <> "")
    dummy = UpdateRange.Replace(ReplaceCell.Value, "", xlPart, , True)
    dummy = UpdateRange.Replace("  ", " ", xlPart)
    Set ReplaceCell = ReplaceCell.Offset(1, 0)
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for this! 

I just tried this and it didn't work throughout the list, but I can confirm that it did work somewhat. The E column has multiple text within its cells and are about +1000 cells. The H column has the text that needs to be deleted from cells in E. The H column has text in Individual cells and goes upto +6000. As I said before, the H column serves as a reference as to what needs to be deleted from Column E. 

That said, can the code be changed to reflect the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Insert as shown

```
    if (Range("E"&row).value="") then
      Exit Do
    End if
```

After the 2 **Range("E" &row)** commands add the above.

This way once you replace the value with NULL there is no point searching the rest of the column H since E is NULL.  So if E is NULL on row 2 there is no point is searching row 3-1000 in column H so break out of the loop and move on to E3.

Also the order of column H is critical.  If possible the most common matches should be at the top of the column H so it doesn't have to search as much of H as it would if the list was unordered or random.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and I tested this one out and there Is an error. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Sorry but i'm new at this.

Comment: @Jase what is the error?

Comment: There was a bit of highlighted text before with an error pop up. I read your instructions again and its running now. Btw, I dont know if it matters or not, but the two loop commands are still there. When i tried to delete it, another error said that it cant do this without a loop command, so i added that bit of code back in.

Comment: This code is taking forever to compete... Isnt there an easier and quicker way to get desired results? The other user was kind enough to write a code, but I am still trying to work out kinks. This has been a frustrating few days.

Comment: Leave both loops in for now. I have a couple more ideas, let me know if that is any faster.  If cell E1 contains a **full match** from H you could do a  **If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("E" & Row).Value, Range("H:H"), 1, False) <> False Then Range("e" & Row).Value = ""** but does H full match E?

Comment: I will get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, the multiple text in E cells up to E600 all match with text in H cells up to 6000 (because they are in individual cells). The texts in E are separated with a space. e.g. xyz@xyz.com zzz@xyz.com and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm joining late to the party, but I would like to put my two cents to the solutions.

This code will look for values on `column H` (8) and replace them for `""` on column E.

Instead of going cell by cell on column E it makes the replacement on the full column, So it will do a single loop on the values on column H.

```
Public Sub big_search()
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
thisrow = 1
existe = True
inicio = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss")
While existe
    ' keep in mind that the column H is the 8th
    selectionvalue = wks.Cells(thisrow, 8)
    If selectionvalue <> "" Then
        wks.Columns("E").Replace What:=selectionvalue, Replacement:="", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
        thisrow = thisrow + 1
    Else
        existe = False
    End If
Wend
fin = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss")
a = MsgBox(fin - inicio & " seconds", vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```